# What's proper abbreviation?

Tags: abbreviations

Can anyone tell me the correct way to write this? I'm putting it etched in glass and want to make sure the abbreviations are all correct.
5lb 12oz 20in
OR
5lbs 12ozs 20ins

Comment: What does 2Oins mean?

Comment: The length of a fish that someone caught? Or a baby?

Comment: There should be a space (though not necessarily a full space) between the numbers and the units: and since the first two are conjoined (it's really "5 lb **and** 12 oz"), they ought to be separated a little more from the third, which is length not weight. I'd suggest _5 lb 12 oz_ on one line and _20 in_ on the next. You could spell out _inches_ if you like, to balance the lines, and put a comma between _lb_ and _12,_ too.